# Generalised Putnam 1967

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

It is known from [Putnam 1967 problem, integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/406998/putnam-1967-problem-integration) we have
\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 f(x)g(nx)dx=\int_0^1g(x)dx\int_0^1f(x)dx
\end{align*}
for $g$ is a bounded, continuous function with period $1$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$. Can we generalise this as follows?

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded, measurable, periodic function with period $1$ and $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then the similar result is true, that is
\begin{align*}
\lim \limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)g(nx) dx=\left( \int_0^1g(x)dx \right)  \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)dx \right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you have a case backing the conjecture?

Comment: @egreg I think it is true by taking $g(x)=\sin(x)$ and $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$